# Read ppm header information and output to console and output file in C

Tags: c, ppm

Beginning to learn C; I'm trying to read and process characters as I come to them while discarding whitespace characters. I need to also determine if it's a comment '#' or the first character of the next input value. The goal is to obtain and write the magic number, width, height, and maxval to a new file.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

char buffer[100];
int num_chars = 0;
FILE *input;
input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

FILE *output;
output = fopen(argv[2], "w");

if (input == NULL){
    printf("ERROR: Input file needed!");
    return -1;
}

if (output == NULL){
    printf("ERROR: Output file needed!");
    return -1;
}

for (int i = fgetc(input); i != EOF; i = fgetc(input)) {

    if (isspace(i)){
        printf("The magic number is: %c\n", i);
        ungetc(i, input);
    } else if (i == '#') {
        for (int j = i; isspace(j); j = fgetc(input)){
            buffer[num_chars++] = j;
            printf("Comment found: %c\n", j);
            ungetc(i, input);
        }
    }


}


return 0;
}
```

*Edit*: utilized suggested isspace function but have created an infinite loop without seeing how. I apologize but I'm not sure what sort of questions I am suppose to be asking.

Comment: Your compiler isn't telling you what's wrong? Always turn on a healthy set of warnings (Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang).

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Netpbm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) formats are a bit odd, in that many programmers initially read them incorrectly.

Simply put, the "magic number" (`P1` to `P7`) must be at the beginning of the file, followed by the header fields, followed by a single whitespace character, followed by the data.  The trick is that each header field may be *preceded* by whitespace and/or comment, and the header is followed by a single whitespace character.

The `P7` format, Portable Arbitrary Map file, has named header fields, but it is rarely supported format anyway, so I'll limit to the common `P1` to `P6` formats only. (To support its header fields, you only need another helper function, though.)

You need four helper functions:

1. A function to convert decimal digit to its numeric value.

   ```
   static int  decimal_digit(const int c)
   {
       switch (c) {
       case '0': return 0;
       case '1': return 1;
       case '2': return 2;
       case '3': return 3;
       case '4': return 4;
       case '5': return 5;
       case '6': return 6;
       case '7': return 7;
       case '8': return 8;
       case '9': return 9;
       default: return -1;
       }
   }
   ```

   Often, you'll see this shortened to `(c - '0')`, (or  `((c >= '0' && c <= '9') ? (c - '0') : -1)` if you want an expression equivalent to the function above), but that only works if the operating system uses a character set where decimal digits are consecutive code points. (They are, except on machines using EBCDIC or some other non-ASCII compatible character sets; very rare nowadays.)
2. A function to read the magic number.

   ```
   int  pnm_magic(FILE *in)
   {
       int  c;

       if (!in || ferror(in))
           return -2;  /* Invalid file handle. */

       c = getc(in);
       if (c != 'P')
           return -1;  /* Not a NetPBM file. */

       switch (getc(in)) {
       case '1': return 1;  /* Ascii PBM */
       case '2': return 2;  /* Ascii PGM */
       case '3': return 3;  /* Ascii PPM */
       case '4': return 4;  /* Binary PBM */
       case '5': return 5;  /* Binary PGM */
       case '6': return 6;  /* Binary PPM */
       /* case '7': return 7; for Portable Arbitrary map file */
       default: return -1;  /* Unknown format */ 
       }
   }
   ```

   Using a helper function to parse the magic number is not absolutely necessary, of course, but using one definitely makes your code easier to read, verify, and maintain. So using one is a good thing.
3. A function to read the whitespace character at the end of the header.

   ```
   int  pnm_endheader(FILE *in)
   {
       int  c;

       if (!in || ferror(in))
           return -1;  /* Invalid file handle. */

       c = getc(in);

       /* Whitespace? */
       if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\v' ||
           c == '\f' || c == '\r' || c == ' ')
           return 0;

       /* Nope, error. Don't consume the bad character. */
       if (c != EOF)
           ungetc(c, in);

       return -1;
   }
   ```

   Note that this function returns 0 if successful, nonzero if an error occurs.
4. A function to parse a header field value, a nonnegative integer.

   Note that this function skips *leading* whitespace and comments, but leaves the character that terminated the value in the stream (via `ungetc()`).

   ```
   int  pnm_value(FILE *in)
   {
       unsigned int  val, old;
       int           c, digit;

       if (!in || ferror(in))
           return -1;  /* Invalid file handle. */

       /* Skip leading ASCII whitespace and comments. */
       c = getc(in);
       while (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\v' ||
              c == '\f' || c == '\r' || c == ' ' || c == '#')
           if (c == '#') {
               /* Skip the rest of the comment */
               while (c != EOF && c != '\n' && c != '\r')
                   c = getc(in);
           } else
               c = getc(in);

       /* Parse initial decimal digit of value. */
       val = decimal_digit(c);
       if (val < 0)
           return -2; /* Invalid input. */

       while (1) {
           c = getc(in);

           /* Delimiter? End of input? */
           if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\v' ||
               c == '\f' || c == '\r' || c == ' ' || c == '#') {
               /* Do not consume the character following the value. */
               ungetc(c, in);
               return val;
           } else
           if (c == EOF)
               return val;

           /* Is it a decimal digit? */
           digit = decimal_digit(c);
           if (digit < 0)
               return -2; /* Invalid input. */

           /* Convert, checking for overflow. */
           old = val;
           val = (val * 10) + digit;
           if (val / 10 != old)
               return -3; /* Overflow. */
       }
   }
   ```

Remember:

- `P1` and `P4` formats have two header fields: *width* and *height*, in that order.
- `P2`, `P3`, `P5`, and `P6` formats have three header fields: *width*, *height*, and *maxval*.
- You can use `fscanf(handle, "%u", &value)` to read each pixel from `P1` and `P2` format files, assuming `unsigned int value;`. It will return 1 if successful. For `P1`, value will be 0 or 1; for `P2`, it will be from 0 to *maxval*, inclusive.
- You can use `fscanf(handle, "%u %u %u", &red, &green, &blue)` to read each pixel from `P3` format files, assuming `unsigned int red, green, blue;`. It will return 3 if successful. Then, each component will be from 0 to *maxval*, inclusive.
- `P4` format is the nastiest to read. It is best done one row of pixels at once, using `fread(buf, width, 1, handle)`, with `unsigned char buf[width];` or a similar-sized dynamically allocated array. Then, pixel `x` is `!!(buf[x/8] & (1 << (x & 7)))` (0 being white, 1 being black; with *x* from 0 to *width*-1). (The `!!` is a double-not, or not-not operator: It yields 0 if the argument is 0, and 1 otherwise.)
- For `P5` format, if *maxval* >= 256, then each pixel consists of two bytes. You can use

  ```
  static float p5_gray(FILE *in, int maxval)
  {
      if (maxval >= 256 && maxval < 65536) {
          int  hi, lo;
          hi = fgetc(in);
          lo = fgetc(in);
          if (lo == EOF)
              return -1.0f;
          return (float)(hi*256 + lo) / (float)maxval;
      } else
      if (maxval >= 1 && maxval < 256) {
          int  val;
          val = fgetc(in);
          if (val == EOF)
              return -1.0f;
          return (float)val / (float)maxval;
      } else
          return -2.0f;
  }
  ```

  to read each pixel from `P5` format. The function returns 0.0f for white, 1.0f for black.
- For `P6` format, if *maxval* >= 256, then each pixel is 6 bytes; otherwise each pixel is three bytes. You can use e.g.

  ```
  static int p6_rgb(FILE *in, int maxval, float *red, float *green, float *blue)
  {
      const float    max = (float)maxval;
      unsigned char  buf[6];

      if (maxval >= 256 && maxval < 65536) {
          if (fread(buf, 6, 1, in) != 1)
              return -1; /* Error! */
          if (red)
              *red = (float)(buf[0]*256 + buf[1]) / max;
          if (green)
              *green = (float)(buf[2]*256 + buf[1]) / max;
          if (blue)
              *blue = (float)(buf[4]*256 + buf[5]) / max;
          return 0;
      } else
      if (maxval >= 1 && maxval < 256) {
          if (fread(buf, 3, 1, in) != 1)
              return -1; /* Error! */
          if (red)
              *red = (float)buf[0] / max;
          if (green)
              *green = (float)buf[1] / max;
          if (blue)
              *blue = (float)buf[2] / max;
          return 0;
      } else
          return -2; /* Invalid maxval */
  }
  ```

  to read each pixel from a `P6` format file.

So, if `in` is an open file handle (or say `stdin`), and you have `int format, width, height, maxval;`, you can do

```
format = pnm_magic(in);
if (format < 1 || format > 6) {
    /* Unrecognized format; fail! */
}

width = pnm_value(in);
if (width <= 0) {
    /* Invalid width; fail! */
}

height = pnm_value(in);
if (height <= 0) {
    /* Invalid height; fail! */
}

if (format == 2 || format == 3 || format == 5 || format == 6) {
    maxval = pnm_value(in);
    if (maxval < 1 || maxval > 65535) {
        /* Invalid maxval; fail! */
    }
}

if (pnm_endheader(in)) {
    /* Bad end of header; fail! */
}
```

to parse the header, leaving the file position at the beginning of the pixel data.

Comment: Thanks for the step by step clarification!

Answer (score 0):

`for (int j = i; i != ' ' || i != '\n'; j = fgetc(input))`

You are using expression that is dependent on i, yet you change `j`.

Then in the loop you do:

`buffer[num_chars++] = j;`

which will eventually overflow.

Probably you meant:

`for (int j = i; j != ' ' || j != '\n'; j = fgetc(input))`

But why don't you use standard functions like `isspace()`?

Also check for buffer overflow:

```
    for (int j = i; j != ' ' || j != '\n'; j = fgetc(input)){
        assert(num_chars < sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(*buffer);
        buffer[num_chars++] = j;
        printf("Comment found: %s\n", j);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't aware of that function but regardless it seems like I have created an endless loop.